# Get values inside a div which is iterated by a foreach loop in Jquery mvc4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, foreach-loop-container

Am displaying values which is model binded by a Foreach loop.And loop is iterating Div instead of table row.I want to get the values inside jquery function .I dont know how to get i have tried a lot.
here is my code:-

```
     @foreach(var p in Model.Cart)
                                   {

                                    a++;

         <div class="container">
            <div class="container-fluid" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-horizontal" style="display:flex;flex: 1 1 auto;">
                        <div class="img-square-wrapper">
                            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="@Url.Content(p.img)" alt="Card image cap" style="height:150px;width:150px">
<input type="hidden" id="mid">@p.mid</input>
                            <h1 style="display:none">@p.mid</h1>
                            <div class="invert" id="count">
                                        <div class="quantity">
                                            <div class="quantity-select">
                                                <div class="entry value-minus" id="minus">&nbsp;</div>
                                                <div class="entry value" id="counter">@p.mcount</div>
                                                <div class="entry value-plus active" id="plus">&nbsp;</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">@p.mname</h4>
                            <h5 class="card-text" id="prize"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:20px"></i> @p.totalprize</h5>
                            <h1 style="display:none" id="pri" data-val="@p.mprize">@p.mprize</h1>
                          <a  id="close1" onclick="return onclickFunction(@p.mid)"> <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:24px;color:red"></i> Remove</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">Deliver Within a Weak</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

         </div>
                    }
```

> Jquery

```
$('.entry.value-plus.active').click(function () {


        var row = $(this).closest(".card");
        var mid = $(row).children('#mid').val();
        var quantity = parseInt($(row).children('#count').text()) + 1; //parseInt($(row).children('#counter').text(),10);
        var a = parseInt($(row).children('#pri').text());
        var upprize = quantity * a;

        alert("mid="+mid+"\n"+"quantity="+quantity+"\n"+"prize="+upprize);
    });
```

Comment: first thing, where is your `#mid`?, second thing when you are working inside foreach you can not use static id for controlls because it creates same id for multiple controll.
so first define which div's value you want.

Comment: @ShantanuSharma, you do not need to comment same thing, which is already commented.

Comment: please use class instead of using ID in Html, So please Re-edit this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to apply class instead of id for all that elements, which values you want in js code, then you need to fetch value using `parent()` method. I have created two div's with different type of value, check it.

```js
 $('.entry.value-plus.active').click(function () {

        var mid = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.mid').text();
        var quantity = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.counter').text());
        var a = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.card-body').children('.pri').text();
        var upprize = quantity * a;

        alert("mid=" + mid + "\n" + "quantity=" + quantity + "\n" + "prize=" + upprize);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container entry value-plus active">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-horizontal" style="display:flex;flex: 1 1 auto;">
                        <div class="img-square-wrapper">
                            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="test" alt="Card image cap" style="height:150px;width:150px">
                            <h1 style="display:none" class="mid">MID value1</h1>
                            <div class="invert" id="count">
                                <div class="quantity">
                                    <div class="quantity-select">
                                        <div class="entry value-minus" id="minus">&nbsp;</div>
                                        <div class="entry value counter" id="counter">15</div>
                                        <div class="entry value-plus active" id="plus">&nbsp;click me</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">MNAME</h4>
                            <h5 class="card-text" id="prize"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:20px"></i> TOTALPRIZE</h5>
                            <h1 style="display:none" id="pri" class="pri" data-val="mprize">5000</h1>
                            <a id="close1" onclick="return onclickFunction(MID)"> <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:24px;color:red"></i> Remove</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">Deliver Within a Weak</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-horizontal" style="display:flex;flex: 1 1 auto;">
                        <div class="img-square-wrapper">
                            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="test" alt="Card image cap" style="height:150px;width:150px">
                            <h1 style="display:none" class="mid">MID value2</h1>
                            <div class="invert" id="count">
                                <div class="quantity">
                                    <div class="quantity-select">
                                        <div class="entry value-minus" id="minus">&nbsp;</div>
                                        <div class="entry value counter" id="counter">25</div>
                                        <div class="entry value-plus active" id="plus">&nbsp;click me</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">MNAME</h4>
                            <h5 class="card-text" id="prize"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:20px"></i> TOTALPRIZE</h5>
                            <h1 style="display:none" id="pri" class="pri" data-val="mprize">10000</h1>
                            <a id="close1" onclick="return onclickFunction(MID)"> <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:24px;color:red"></i> Remove</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">Deliver Within a Weak</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: your comment has a code error. remove the . from the classname.

<div class="container entry.value-plus.active">

Answer (score 0):

I notice few inconsistencies as stated below.

1. For `input` you have to assign `value` with `attribute` like below.

`<input type="hidden" id="mid" value="@p.mid" />`

2. For getting `quantity` value I guess you should be using `#counter` instead of `#count` like below.

`var quantity = parseInt($(row).children('#counter').text()) + 1;`